# Visual Basic 6 - Error: [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver] You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6, odbc

[image: picture of form]

I am getting an error, in the 24th line. I know my syntax is correct and ADO controls are connected properly, but I am still getting an error sql syntax not correct. Why does this happen?

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver] You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

code --

```
Private Sub cmdReserve_Click()
If txtAdvance < 500 Then
MsgBox "Room Advance Should Be Above 500"
txtAdvance.Text = ""
Exit Sub
End If
lblTotal.Caption = Val(txtDays.Text) * Val(txtRcharge.Text)
lblBalance.Caption = Val(lblTotal.Caption) - Val(txtAdvance.Text)
If (txtRstatus = "AVAILABLE") Then
s1 = txtRNo.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Refresh
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset.AddNew
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("ROOM_NO") = txtRNo.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("CUSTOMER_ID") = txtCid.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("ROOM_TYPE") = cboRType.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("ROOM_STATUS") = "OCCUPIED"
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("CHECK_IN_DATE") = txtCindate.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("CHECK_OUT_DATE") = txtCoutdate.Text
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("NO_OF_DAYS") = Val(txtDays.Text)
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("NO_OF_PEOPLE") = Val(txtPpl.Text)
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("ADVANCE") = Val(txtAdvance.Text)
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("TOTAL_AMOUNT") = lblTotal.Caption
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset("BALANCE_AMOUNT") = lblBalance.Caption
**AdoRooms.RecordSource = "select * from `rooms` where ROOM_NO= '" + s1 + "'"**
AdoRooms.Refresh
AdoRooms.Recordset("ROOM_STATUS") = "OCCUPIED"
AdoRooms.Recordset.Update
AdoReserved_rooms.Recordset.Update
End If
MsgBox "ROOM RESERVED"
cmdReserve.Enabled = False
cmdNext.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: AdoRooms.RecordSource = "select * from `rooms` where ROOM_NO= '" + s1 + "'"

Comment: Thats the line with the error

Comment: Can you show us what the full actual query is?  I don't see anything wrong, but in any case you should switch to using a prepared statement here.

Comment: What is the type of the `ROOM_NO` column?

Comment: Its varchar - length 10 , in both tables rooms and reservedrooms to which AdoRooms and AdoReserved_rooms are connected

Comment: I am using SQLyog to create the database and tables...

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the value of `s1` is which is being used in the query?

Comment: Yes I did , I added another textbox to output the value of s1, (so that i could check the value) and it shows the output correctly

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack. You should use parameterized queries instead of statement concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I had put the `AdoRooms` Control as having the following properties earlier

```
CommandType adcmdTable
Table rooms
```

When I changed it to

```
CommandType adcmdText
Query select * from rooms
```

I got the correct output